# Creating public profile page drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, user-management

Could anyone tell me if the following is achievable in Drupal (for a newbie)

I want to create a registration form that a people have to fill in to become a member of my website.

Once registered I want them to have the facility to log in and edit their public 'profile' page and If possible for them to select multiple items from a predefined list (i.e. using tick boxes) with the selected items becoming visible on their public profile page.

i would also like a single photo upload facility to be used for their profile page photo.

Are there any Drupal modules etc out there which would help me achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the profile module.
[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/user-registration-module-for-drupal) est very close to yours. You could use the answer :)
Also for all details, have a look at the [doc](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/profile). It kind of answers your questions in the content table already ;)

Have fun!